Spring Boot Batch: Some Jobs Do Not Start When Running Concurrently
Problem: I'm encountering an issue with Spring Boot Batch where triggering multiple batch jobs concurrently causes some of them to not start. When I schedule multiple batch executions, only a few begin processing, while the others remain idle without any error messages or logs indicating why they failed to start.
Environment:

Spring Boot Version: 3.0.1

Database: PostgreSQL

Job Repository: Database-backend job repository


Configuration:

The jobs are scheduled using @Scheduled, and each job is configured with its own TaskExecutor.

I'm not explicitly limiting the number of concurrent jobs, but some form of blocking seems to be occurring.


What I Have Tried:

Checked for any database-level locks or issues in the Job Repository tables.

Verified that each job configuration uses its own TaskExecutor.

Increased the maximum pool size for the TaskExecutor.

Ensured there are no dependencies between jobs that could cause blocking.


Observed Behavior: Only a few jobs start executing when triggered, while the rest remain in a "queued" state and do not attempt to start based on the logs.
Question: Could this issue be related to a locking mechanism in the Job Repository or another component? What would be the best approach to debug and identify the cause of this blocking behavior in Spring Batch?
Relevant Code: Here is the code used to trigger and run the jobs:
try {
    segmentJobOperator.run(jobParameters.getString(Constants.JOB_NAME), jobParameters);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

public Future<Long> run(String jobName, JobParameters jobParameters) 
        throws JobInstanceAlreadyExistsException, NoSuchJobException, JobParametersInvalidException {
    return sympanJobOperator.startJobAsync(jobName, jobParameters);
}

@Async
public Future<Long> startJobAsync(String jobName, JobParameters jobParameters)
        throws NoSuchJobException, JobInstanceAlreadyExistsException, JobParametersInvalidException {
    String properties = BatchHelper.propertiesToString(jobParametersConverter.getProperties(jobParameters));
    long jobExecutionId = jobOperator.start(jobName, properties);
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(jobExecutionId);
}


@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CalculateSqlQuerySegmentJobListener implements JobExecutionListener {
    public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        final JobParameters jobParameters = jobExecution.getJobParameters();
        Long segmentId = jobParameters.getLong(Constants.SEGMENT_ID);
        log.info("Before Job for segment[id: {}]", segmentId);
        // Additional setup logic here...
    }
    
    public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        final JobParameters jobParameters = jobExecution.getJobParameters();
        Long segmentId = jobParameters.getLong(Constants.SEGMENT_ID);
        Long correlatorId = jobParameters.getLong(Constants.CORRELATOR_ID);
        log.info("After Job for segment[id: {}]", segmentId);
        // Additional cleanup logic here...
    }
}

